# Windfield documentation isn't working on my project. Love2d

Tags: love2d

So I am currently using a library called windfield. Which you can get [here](https://github.com/a327ex/windfield). It lets you do collison and stuff. The documentation that is listed [here](http://idbrii.com/love-windfield/index.html). The documentation is useful but on
[this](http://idbrii.com/love-windfield/index.html#World:addCollisionClassTable) webpage the code when I import it into my project dosent work.[My Code(in love.load)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d45T0.png) [My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WstfF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and errors as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it like this:

```
world:addCollisionClass("NPC")
world:addCollisionClass("Enemy, {ignores = {"NPC"}})
world:addCollisionClass("Player", {ignores = {"NPC", "Enemy"}})

player = world:newRectangleCollider(350, 100, 80, 80)
player:setCollisionClass("Player") -- player receives "Player" collision class
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [original version](https://github.com/a327ex/windfield) of Windfield, which doesn't include an "addCollisionClassTable" method. The documentation that you were looking at is for idbrii's [updated version](https://github.com/idbrii/love-windfield) of Windfield. You will have to add idbrii's version to your project instead of the original if want to create collision classes in that particular way. Otherwise, you will need to set up collision classes in Windfield the original way (see TempName's answer).